# Missing number, treated as zero when using \If without \EndIf with algpseudocode

Tags: algpseudocode

I'm trying to typeset a pseudo code with an `\If` block without the matching `\EndIf` using `algpseudocode`. This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

    % Insert the algorithm
    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Compute some function by recursive algorithm}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \Function{$some$}{m,n}
            \If{$n=1$ \textit{or} $m=1$}
            \State \Return 1
            \Else
            \State \Return $some(n,m-1)+some(n-1,m)+some(n-1,m-1)$
            \EndFunction
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

But I get the error: `missing number, treated as zero`. What do I do to make the `\If` code without the matching `\EndIf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is because you're missing and `\EndIf`.

The `algpseudocode` package relies on the `\If...\EndIf` structure (like any decent language should) to keep track of the indentation of the code.

If you don't want to show the `\End`s, you can use the `noend` option for `algpseudocode`. Nonetheless you have to use the `\EndIf` for `algpseudocode`'s internal bookkeeping.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
    % Insert the algorithm
    \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{Compute some function by recursive algorithm}
        \begin{algorithmic}[1]
            \Function{$some$}{m,n}
            \If{$n=1$ \textit{or} $m=1$}
            \State \Return 1
            \Else
            \State \Return $some(n,m-1)+some(n-1,m)+some(n-1,m-1)$
            \EndIf % <- Here
            \EndFunction
        \end{algorithmic}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. but I don't want to show "end if" message. can I?

Comment: Did you try `algpseudocode` with the `noend` option (`\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}`)? You must still use the `\EndIf` to tell where the code indentation ends, but it will not be printed.

Comment: Can I change the text "Algorithm1"?